# Object View ID as filter id with StandardSetController limit 10k

Tags: apex, batch

```
Database.QueryLocator ql = Database.getQueryLocator('select id from account limit 1');
ApexPages.StandardSetController setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(ql);

setController.setFilterId(objectviewid);

NumberOfRecords = setController.getResultSize();
```

Showing only 10k even if filter having more than 10k.

Any other way to get it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is documented as

The maximum record limit
for StandardSetController is
10,000 records. Instantiating
StandardSetController using
a query locator returning more than
10,000 records causes a
LimitException to be thrown.
However, instantiating
StandardSetController with a list of
more than 10,000 records doesn’t
throw an exception, and instead
truncates the records to the limit.

You can refer standard document.link on this behaviour

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm

Refer note section.

The solution should be to paginate your list rather than keeping 10000 records.

Comment: But how can i make filter view id? I need to send a mail to all list view records through batch apex.

Comment: Send mails in batches .First mail with 5K and then 5K .Or send the link only to view the records .

Comment: return Database.getQueryLocator(select id,email from contact ); how can i make list view id in query?